# error: non-lvalue in unary `&' in C++

Tags: c++, macros

We are using a macro wrapper to Bind Where Parameter function.

```
#define bindWhereClause(fieldName, fieldDataType, fieldData) _bindWhereClause(fieldName, fieldDataType, sizeof(fieldData), &fieldData)

void _bindWhereClause(const char *name, int dataType, int dataSize, void *data)
{
  // Implementation
}

Database.bindWhereClause( "FIRST_NAME", SQL_VARCHAR, name.getFirstName());
```

When I tried to call the macro with a function as parameter (as above) I am getting the error message "error: non-lvalue in unary `&'".

I am able to call the macro with normal variables like

```
Database.bindWhereClause( "FIRST_NAME", SQL_VARCHAR, firstName);
```

How to resolve this? Do I need to use inline functions instead of macro?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take the address of the return value of a function - it is ephemeral.

You need to use a real variable:

```
Nametype first_name = name.getFirstName();
Database.bindWhereClause( "FIRST_NAME", SQL_VARCHAR, first_name);

// ... and maybe name.setFirstName(first_name); here
```

Using an inline function would make it compile but it is unlikely to actually *work*.  Presumably this is followed by something like:

```
Database.execute();
```

...which expects the objects whose addresses you passed earlier to still be valid.  If you use an inline function instead of a macro, those objects will no longer exist, since they were just local to the inline function which has already exited.

Comment: Yes Caf, I am executing the query in the next step. Thanks for the suggestion, I have implemented in this way.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you will be just fine using an inline function. It is much better in general and you should use inline functions unless using macros is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The macro expands to:

```
_bindWhereClause("FIRST_NAME", SQL_VARCHAR, sizeof(name.getFirstName()), &name.getFirstName())
```

You can't take the address of the return value of a function, so that's invalid. You can take the address of a variable or argument, so yes, turning it into a function with actual arguments would work.

Comment: "You can't take the address of the return value of a function" you are actually, as in  std:::vector::value_type& std::vector operator(size_t) , you are able to do &my_vector[0] because it returns a reference: an l-value

Comment: ... as you are able to do my_vector[0] = "hello world" when your vector contains string

Comment: You are, of course, right. I couldn't find a way to say it any more precisely without distracting from the actual point, but I was specifically talking about a returned *value* as opposed to a returned *reference*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a wrapper class around Database.

Check out the Decorator pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern